# send JSON object from client to server using Ajax (client) and CSHTML (server)

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I am trying to: 
1. Send a JSON object from client to server
2. Parse the object at server side.
3. Encode some fields from the original object and send it as ne JSON object to client side.

This is my current code:

Client (JQuery-Ajax):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj['marks']= ["hi"]; //array 
    $.getJSON("ServerTest.cshtml", JSON.stringify(obj) , function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, field) {
            if (i == "TextToSend") {
                $('#inner_body').append('<div class="abc">' + field + '</div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Server (CSHTML):

```
@{
    //Recieve and convert JSON Array
    var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
    var jsonA = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var objArray= Json.Decode(jsonA);

    // Create a JSON Array
    var ServerResponse = new {
    TextToSend = new string[1],
    };

    ServerResponse.TextToSend[0] = objArray.marks[0];

    var json = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ServerResponse));
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(json);
    Response.End();
}
```

It is not working. I assume that the server side code is not reading the JSON object properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an HTTP GET, which is intended to receive data at the client from a server. You should be doing a POST, which is intended to send data to a server.

On the server side, you should be writing an action in the controller to receive the data from the client, and you should put the HttpPost attribute on the action.

I know that you are going to ask how to do that, but the best way for you to find out the answer to that question is not for me to write a huge article about it here, or even to show you the code, but instead for you to do a tutorial on creating an MVC app with Code First, for example, and have scaffolding build a controller for the models that you create in the tutorial, and then look at the Create, Edit and Delete actions that are created for you.

The client forms don't visibly use AJAX, since it is all hidden away by the HTML form mechanism. As far as the AJAX client side code is concerned, you can look at the jQuery documentation for $post, paying attention to the type (4th) parameter.

Razor is for the V (view) part of MVC, and not for receiving data from the client.